# Difference between set-cookie2 and set-cookie

Tags: http, httpwebrequest, http-headers

Is there any advantage of using set-cookie2 over set-cookie.
And is there any difference in how they affect the functionality on server and client side.

Answer (score 26):

Set-Cookie2 isn't widely implemented and now deprecated.

See [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265).

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Answer (score 10):

First of all Set-Cookie2 is [deprecated as of RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) and should not be used. But as for the differences between Set-Cookie and Set-Cookie2:

Set-Cookie2 allowed you to restrict your cookie to a list of ports to which the cookie may be sent. According to [RFC2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965):

> The Port attribute restricts the port to which a cookie may be
> returned in a Cookie request header.  Note that the syntax REQUIREs
> quotes around the OPTIONAL portlist even if there is only one portnum
> in portlist.
>
> There are three possible behaviors, depending on the Port attribute in
> the Set-Cookie2 response header:
>
> 1. By default (no Port attribute), the cookie MAY be sent to any  port.
> 2. If the attribute is present but has no value (e.g., Port), the  cookie MUST only be sent to the request-port it was received  from.
> 3. If the attribute has a port-list, the cookie MUST only be  returned if the new request-port is one of those listed in  port-list.

This differs because Set-Cookie does not allow you to restrict cookies to any specific ports. Therefore your cookies are sent to any port on that host no matter the port number.