# apache 2.4 modules: writing new cookie on the response cause seg fault

Tags: c, apache

I'm writing apache module and I'm having difficulties writing a new cookie to be sent to the browser with the response.

I'm trying to use [`ap_cookie_write`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/httpd/trunk/doxygen/group__APACHE__CORE__COOKIE.html) as stated in the documentation.

First question - I don't think setting cookie on the `request_rec` will result with sending the cookie back to the client, so how can I really add cookies?

Second question - 
This code:

```
if (ap_cookie_write(ctx->r, "_mycookie", "", NULL,  0L) != APR_SUCCESS) {
     ERROR(ctx->r->server, "Could not write _mycookie empty value");
}
```

causes this crash:

```
[Wed Aug 03 10:09:51.712610 2016] [core:debug] [pid 17272:tid 140219016423168] util_cookies.c(59): [client 10.20.1.35:52967] AH00007: ap_cookie: user '(null)' set cookie: '_mycookie=;HttpOnly;Secure;Version=1', referer: http://10.20.1.203/
[Wed Aug 03 10:09:52.389575 2016] [core:notice] [pid 32421:tid 140219219822464] AH00051: child pid 17272 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

What am I doing wrong? by looking at the [source code](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/server/util_cookies.c) I see that there it no need to allocate the strings I'm sending there.

**Update**

As for the second question - I figured out that the `varargs` list must end with `NULL` so that fixed the seg fault:

```
if (ap_cookie_write(ctx->r, "_mycookie", "", NULL,  0L, NULL) != APR_SUCCESS) {
     ERROR(ctx->r->server, "Could not write _mycookie empty value");
}
```

But now the cookie does not return on the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide [`ap_cookie_write`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/httpd/trunk/doxygen/group__APACHE__CORE__COOKIE.html#ga9659efc3add1bc9f58e30752264dc01a) the header table(s) to add the cookie to. As the documentation says:

> A varargs array of zero or **more (apr_table_t *) tables** followed by
>   NULL to which the cookies should be added.

**What do cookies have to do with headers?**

Cookies are added/removed via the [Set-Cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie) (or [Set-Cookie2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462180/difference-between-set-cookie2-and-set-cookie)) header.

**Why does the header table need to be provided?**

request_rec instances have two header tables, headers_out and err_headers_out.

> The difference between headers_out and err_headers_out, is that the
>   latter are printed even on error, and persist across internal
>   redirects (so the headers printed for ErrorDocument handlers will have
>   them).
>
> For example, if a handler wants to return a 404 response, but
>   nevertheless to set a cookie, it has to be:
>
> $r->err_headers_out->add('Set-Cookie' => $cookie);   return
>   Apache2::Const::NOT_FOUND; If the handler does:
>
> $r->headers_out->add('Set-Cookie' => $cookie);   return
>   Apache2::Const::NOT_FOUND; the Set-Cookie header won't be sent.

([Source](https://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/RequestRec.html#C_err_headers_out_))

As such, `ap_cookie_write` cannot know which header table(s), if any, to use. You could provide other unrelated tables if you wanted.

In your case, you likely want to do:

```
request_rec *r = ctx->r;
ap_cookie_write(r, "_mycookie", "", NULL,  0L, r->headers_out, r->err_headers_out, NULL);
```